# How do I set the position of a QProgressDialog to be in the centre of the main window?@

Tags: qt

I'm using a QProgressDialog at the start of my application to show the progress of data being loaded.

The dialog opens in the centre of the screen.  In these days of multiple screens that is not ideal behaviour.

How can I tell the dialog to open in the centre of the application's main window?

Comment: What happens if you set the main window as the parent of the QProgress Dialog?

Comment: Ah!  Is that how its supposed to work?  I'm calling it from within a treeview setupModelData() method.  I'm not sure how to get the main window from there.  I'll have a poke around again.

Comment: Ideally, the model should have no interest in displaying UI, such as a progress bar. I would have an update signal from within that method, which emits its progress, then receive it in a slot in a widget, which is responsible for displaying the progress values.

Comment: You are right, Merlin, silly me.  I'll sort that out right away.  Thank you.

Comment: I usually take the dialog's geometry, move the center to wherever I want (your Main Dialog's center in this point), reset the geometry, and then show().